# Чтение из ComPort в QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt, com-port

Вопрос такой:

Есть строка QString и  массив QByteArray.
Я записываю строку в массив `QByteArray NN.append(nname);` и отправляю в СОМ порт.

В com-порте считываю в массив `QByteArray` и пытаюсь вывести строчку в `lineedit`

Данные приходят и правильно, но в не той кодировке(пишется непонятно что)

[image: вот что]

что делать?

[[image: введите сюда описание изображения]]

в компорт записываются (значения сверху)
а из компорта достаются такие (снизу) что с этим делать? как этого избежать?

ЗЫ: другие типы данных( инт) спокойно передаются и корректно отображаются

Comment: Я бы начал с того, что посмотрел какие <b>байты</b> вы получаете из ком-порта и какие в него отправляете.

Comment: Попробуйте без передачи данных записать строку в массив, из массива обратно в строку и вывести -- будет ли правильно? Подозреваю что проблема у вас там где вы преобразуете из массива обратно в строку.

Comment: Проверил, без передачи данных массив выводит корректный результат

Comment: "Приходят правильно, но не в той кодировке", так правильно или нет? Побайтово сравните что отправляете с тем что получаете.

Comment: отправляю: 5
Принимаю : (тут символ который не копируется сюда)
причем что странно был момент когда все хорошо передавалось/принималось, но я не помню что изменил и опять все по новой(

Comment: Вы уверены что на обоих сторонах у вас одинаковые настройки ком-порта? Там довольно много параметров.

Comment: а какой из параметров может влиять на это?
до этого как раз я выставляю настройки на одном порту и передаю в другой и все ок.

Answer (score 2):

Кодировка у ком порта, а точнее у протокола передачи RS-242(COM, UART, USART) вне зависимости от системы ANSII.
Судя по вашему логу скорее всего у вас выставлены разные настройки на ваших устройствах, в Qt при использовании класса QSerialPort нужно учитывать, что там есть предустановленные значения, больше инфы: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html.
также нужно учитывать, что в ANSII нет кириллицы, только латинские буквы, цифры и спец. символы.
У меня ещё косяки возникали, когда я эмулировал 2 ком порта и соединял один с прогой, другой с терминалом, и если отправлять слишком много данных, то эмулятор тупо не успевал обрабатывать, шли потери пакетов и получалась белиберда.

UPD.
В ответ на ваш коммент "какой параметр.." - любой, абсолютно любой, и частота и проверка на чётность и добавление контрольного бита, всё это может нагрешить.

Comment: Спасибо, и вправду дело было в ком порте, с дефолтными настройками все ок. ( но проблему правильной передачи настроек не решило)